Approximate execution time of my circuit on Fake Hardware
I want to find the approximate execution time of my circuit on Fake HW.
What I understand is that if the circuit execution time goes beyond the coherence time i.e., t1 then there is no valid result obtained from a quantum system.
t1 time can be easily calculated using the below lines:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke
        backend = FakeSherbrooke()
        print(backend.qubit_properties(0))
    QubitProperties(t1=0.0002836600405576469, t2=0.00022028362320267883, frequency=4635669322.052242)

But I am really not sure how to find the approximate execution time of my circuit on Fake HW? I am using the qiskit==1.0.
